# Comparing two sets of data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Column A is a list of names and column B details their phone number.  I have an updated list of names and phone numbers in columns C & D .  I want a formula that is able to detail any change of phone number for any individual.  I’d like to see the name of whose number has changed in column E and the new phone number in column F.

Just to complicate things, I’ll be updating the data in column C and D approximately once a month.  This means that the names in columns C won’t always be in column A based on users leaving and users joining.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you already know Excel's [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, it may be not the best one but it works.

So I'll explain, A,B are the lastest updated data, C,D are the previous data
E,F is  the "detail any change" you asked.

You may move columns and or hide them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it. Just following on from your solution, it works but it's based on columns A and C having the names in the same order.  What if this weren't the case?

Comment: You need to keep the order, if its not in order, it wont work because the formula will check if it`s the same. You can move the CD columns to the right if you want.

Comment: By the way it`s in french, put  IF instead of SI, If it`s not in order it will check the wrong name...

Comment: You shoulkd delete a row if someone leaves

Comment: Yeah I got it working.  I was just wondering if it could be done using a different method if the names weren't in any particular order?

Comment: It is possible, it could be done using a different method if the names weren't in any particular order.

Comment: Can you share? :)

Comment: Oh, It`s possible yes but doing it is another story.

Comment: I knew that much!!

Comment: You can always sort your list without problem.